# How do I create SKTextureAtlas at run time from plist in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, texturepacker, texture-atlas

I load textures from net. Textures are created with TexturePacker for SpriteKit. I can create Atlas only from textures that I have at compilation moment.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question need to be more detailed. See [help] on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Either use Texture Packer or use SKTextureAtlas.  Going from Texture Packer to SKTextureAtlas is defeating the purpose of the optimizations that Texture Packer provides.  (Texture Packer generates an atlas on its own, this atlas is not compatible with SKTextureAtlas)